# Can volume automatically decrease during communication activity?

Tags: software-recommendation, audio, voip

A feature of Windows 7 that I really like that it can decrease the volume of system sounds/music by 50%/80%/mute entirely when it senses communication activity, ie. Skype call, Google Voice call, etc.

Is it possible to do this in OS X either out of the box or with a third party app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype has a preference called "Pause iTunes during calls", enabled by default. In "Telephone" it's called "Pause iTunes during call" and iChat pauses iTunes automatically, without any preference. There is no system-wide setting however, but there are not many phone apps remaining than those as well.

Comment: Yeah I could see Apple using this in their Facetime stuff.

Comment: This is good info.  I use Google Voice most of the time so, I was hoping for something that would work with that.

Comment: You can use iChat with Google Talk and Voice, but unfortunately not the normal landline/cell calls.